# PowerShell: "No positional parameter found"

Tags: powershell, scripting, active-directory, global

File.csv contains a list of groups that are in different domains. I'm trying to recursively pull the list of users in the list but it keeps giving me the following at at $adgroup:"No positional parameter found"

```
$groups = Get-Content -path 'C:\Temp\file.csv'

$result = foreach ($group in $groups)
{​​​​​​​
    foreach ($domain in $domains)
    {​​​​​​​

        $adGroup = Get-ADGroup $group -Searchbase "" -server thegc:3268
        $x = ($x.DistinguishedName -split ',DC=')[1]
        $members = (Get-ADGroupMember $adGroup -Server $x -recursive).where({​​​​​​​
                


                $_.ObjectClass -eq 'User' 
            
            }​​​​​​​)
            
            foreach($user in $members)
            {​​​​​​​


                [pscustomobject]@{​​​​​​​
                    GroupName = $adGroup.Name
                    samAccountName = $user.samAccountName
                    distinguishedName = $user.distinguishedName
                    name = $user.name
                }​​​​​​​
            }​​​​​​​
        }​​​​​​​
    }​​​​​​


$result | Export-Csv c:\temp\output.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Any help would be appreciated here-

Comment: Which line/command is throwing the error?

Comment: for the first script: $members = (Get-ADGroupMember $adGroup -Recursive -Server thegc:3268).where({                                        for the second script: $adGroup = Get-ADGroup -filter $group -searchbase "" -server thegc:3268

Comment: Oh probably can't use GC port, try with LDAP / LDAP over SSL ports

Comment: ldapfilter throws "cannot validate argument on parameter 'server' error

Comment: Why are you querying the global catalog?

Comment: I'm using GC bc the groups I'm pulling are located in different domains

Comment: Try specifying each parameter for the `Get-ADGroup` cmdlet. Also, I'm not sure it the searchbase can be an empty string.